# Google Drive REST API Notifications not working for changes in app folder

Tags: android, rest, notifications, google-drive-api

According to the documentation it should be possible to register a notification channel for changes to the app folder of my app, using `setSpaces("appDataFolder")`.

However, I only get an initial `sync` notification when setting up the channel, but no `change` notifications when I change something in the app folder.

If I use `setSpaces("drive")` or omit the `setSpaces()` altogether and change something in regular drive space, I receive `change` notifications alright.

I didn't find anything about watching for changes in the app folder, so I hope someone here can help me.

This is how I set up the channel, where `mDrive` is a fully initialized and authorized instance of `com.google.api.services.drive.Drive`

```
channelId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
channelExpiration = System.currentTimeMillis() + CHANNEL_LIVETIME_MILLIS;
Channel channel = new Channel();
channel.setType("web_hook");
channel.setId(channelId);
channel.setAddress(DRIVE_API_CALLBACK_RECEIVER_URL);
channel.setToken("...");
channel.setExpiration(channelExpiration);
Channel result = mDrive.changes().watch(channel).setSpaces("appDataFolder").execute();
```

Comment: I'm a bit confuse with your question. is the issue with android or web (http)?

Comment: @Andres I'm using the REST API from an Android project (as I need features the Android Drive API does not provide). From the Android app I trigger that watch(channel) request, telling Google Drive to notify an AppEngine backend part for my app (the channel's address). All of this works fine, except when I do that 'setSpaces("appDataFolder")'

Comment: It sounds like a bug and/or an undocumented "limitation" in the Drive API.  You could consider filing a report on the official Google Apps API issue tracker:  https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/list

Comment: I tested this as well, and it does appear to be a bug. I've filed a bug internally with the engineering team, but if you want updates on the progress please file a bug on the issue tracker linked in the previous comment.

Comment: @EricKoleda Thanks a lot for your comment, I will do this.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a scope where you set this up? Make sure you have a broad enough scope to include 'appDataFolder'. By this I mean you should be able to get some results from this (from [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/appdata)):

```
/**
 * Print metadata for the Application Data folder.
 *
 * @param service Drive API service instance.
 */
private static void printApplicationDataFolderMetadata(Drive service) {
  try {
    File file = service.files().get("appfolder").execute();

    System.out.println("Id: " + file.getId());
    System.out.println("Title: " + file.getTitle());
  } catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("An error occured: " + e);
  }
}
```

I think the above might be your problem. Whereever you are setting scope make sure to include the `drive.appfolder` or more formally

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appfolder
```

Furthermore,  are you checking if result is null? You really should put the `Channel result =...` line in a `try {} catch(IOExeption e) {}` and print the error if there is one like in this example (from [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/changes/watch#examples)).

```
  /**
   * Watch for all changes to a user's Drive.
   *
   * @param service Drive API service instance.
   * @param channelId Unique string that identifies this channel.
   * @param channelType Type of delivery mechanism used for this channel.
   * @param channelAddress Address where notifications are delivered.
   * @return The created channel if successful, {@code null} otherwise.
   */
  private static Channel watchChange(Drive service, String channelId,
      String channelType, String channelAddress) {
    Channel channel = new Channel();
    channel.setId(channelId);
    channel.setType(channelType);
    channel.setAddress(channelAddress);
    try {
      return service.changes().watch(channel).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      // ADD A LOG OR PRINT STATEMENT HERE 
      Log.e("DRIVEAPI", "Error: " + e.toString())
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Which for you code should look like this:

```
channelId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
channelExpiration = System.currentTimeMillis() + CHANNEL_LIVETIME_MILLIS;
Channel channel = new Channel();
channel.setType("web_hook");
channel.setId(channelId);
channel.setAddress(DRIVE_API_CALLBACK_RECEIVER_URL);
channel.setToken("...");
channel.setExpiration(channelExpiration);
try {
    Channel result = mDrive.changes().watch(channel).setSpaces("appDataFolder").execute();
    if(result != null) {
        // do whatever you want with result Channel
    } else {
        Log.e("DRIVEAPI", "Error: result is null for some reason!");
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace()
    Log.e("DRIVEAPI", "Error: " + e.toString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the scope must be okay, as I can read and write from the appfolder and, as said above, notifications work fine if I use 'drive' instead of 'appDataFolder'. As for the channel -- it is not null. As said above, I get the initial 'sync' notification via the channel, but no further 'change' notifications.